# MacPro Hard Drive 3 TB or Larger formatted to Logical Volume Group by Disk Utility

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, mac-pro

I have an Intel MacPro in which I recently installed a new internal 3TB hard disk.

I attempted to format it in Disk Utility using the standard GUID partition map and encountered a strange problem. **Disk Utility formatted it using a *Logical Volume Group (LVG)* instead of GUID.**

Furthermore, Disk Utility subsequently refused to allow me to reformat or repartition this drive. The *Partition Layout* drop-down in Disk Utility is greyed-out. I seem to be stuck with a LVG drive.

#### Specifics

> Model: MacPro Quad Core (Early 2009/Nehalem MacPro4,1)
> System: OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.5
> Disk Utility: Version 13 (450)
> Hard Disk: Seagate Barracuda ST3000DM001 3TB

*How can I remove the Logical Volume Group partition scheme and reformat this drive in the GUID standard recommend by Apple?*

Comment: The only issue I have when doing this is that I can no longer create a bootcamp partition. When I let OS X (10.8) reformat using a logical volume, I have no issues using bootcamp assistant. Only issue is that i have a waisted 800gig logical volume and can no longer create a data partition. If i use the method above and let OS X (10.6) reformat, it lets me using the GUID partition scheme, but when I go to run Boot Camp Assistant, i get the "The startup disk cannot be partitioned or restored to a single partition"... even though it shows I currently have 1 3TB Macintosh HD partition created with

Comment: @g8orballboy I have not used Boot Camp Assistant with this scenario. Are you using Boot Camp Assistant 10.6, or a later version?

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been reported to occur on Intel MacPro's using internal drives from various manufactures with capacities >= 3 TB. Specifically, it's been reported when using *Disk Utility* in OS X *Mountain Lion (10.8)* and *Mavericks (10.9).*

Although there have been solutions involving using *diskutil* in *Terminal* posted here at [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/94204/why-does-my-3tb-seagate-hd-keep-formatting-as-a-logical-volume-group/117526#117526) and [elsewhere](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5144859?start=0&tstart=0) on the web, I found a simpler solution: Format the disk using *Disk Utility* from an **OS X Snow Leopard (10.6) Install DVD.**

---

#### Warning: This solution *will* cause you to lose all data on the drive.

1. Backup any valuable data from the drive in question.
2. Reboot using the OS X Snow Leopard (10.6) Install DVD. (Hold down the *C-Key* to boot from the DVD.)
3. Choose your language (eg. English).
4. Instead of installing OS X, choose *Disk Utility* from the *Utilities* menu.
5. Select your drive from the pane on the left of the *Disk Utility* screen.
6. Choose the *Partition* tab.
7. Select your desired *Partition Layout.*
8. Select *Mac OS Extended (Journaled)* under *Format:*
9. Check the *Options* button and verify that GUID is selected as the partition scheme.
10. Click the *Apply* button and verify you want to proceed.
11. When the partition and format process is complete, quit Disk Utility and reboot.

---

The disk will now be correctly formatted using a GUID partition table.

(If you need to repartition or reformat the drive in the future, you will need to repeat this process. Hopefully Apple will fix this bug in a later version of *Disk Utility.*)